# Trying to access LWC Component from vf page for custom change password feature in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, community, visualforce-component

Please find below code snippets

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <p>Test VF PAge</p>
    <apex:includeLightning />
    
    <div id="lightningvf"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $Lightning.use("c:WebResetPasswordApp", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:webResetPasswordComponent",
          {},
          "lightningvf",
          function(cmp) {
             console.log('LWC Componenet added in VF page');
          });
    }, '{!$Site.BaseUrl}');
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Please find the code for the aura app.

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess" access="GLOBAL" >
    <aura:dependency resource="c:webResetPasswordComponent"/>
</aura:application>
```

Please find code for LWC Component.

```
<template>
  <div>Testing</div>
</template>
```

I have added this vf page into below community setting.
[image]
Here vf page is getting load but LWC component "webResetPasswordComponent" is not rendering and throwing below error.
[image]

Comment: What is the digital experience site's template name?

Comment: It's a Build Your Own (Aura) Template site.

Comment: Hi @ManojKanojiya have you found the solution? I'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: Hi @naveen.singh This is known issue https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000iw1k3/lightning-out-isnt-supported-for-the-change-password-page